# Interpretation of Log Odds in Logistic Regression

Tags: logistic-regression, logarithmic

$\log(\text{odds}) = \text{logit}(P)=ln \big({{P}\over{1-P}}\big)$

$ln\big({{P}\over{1-P}}\big)=\beta_0+\beta_1x$

Consider this example: $0.7=\beta_o+\beta_1(x)+\beta_2(y)+\beta_3(z)$

How can this expression be interpreted?

Answer (score 1):

Lets first understand what does **odds ratio mean** : Let’s say that the probability of success of some event is .8.  Then the probability of failure is 1 – .8 = .2.  The odds of success are defined as the ratio of the probability of success over the probability of failure.
In our example, the odds of success are .8/.2 = 4.  That is to say that the odds of success are  4 to 1.  If the probability of success is .5, i.e., 50-50 percent chance, then the odds of success is 1 to 1.

Why doe we take Log of Odds:
One reason is that it is usually difficult to model a variable which has restricted range, such as probability.  This transformation is an attempt to get around the restricted range problem.  It maps probability ranging between 0 and 1 to log odds ranging from negative infinity to positive infinity.

Now Coming to interpratation:

If this equation gives 0.7 as log of odds it means that the values of x for which it was calculated increases the odds of success by that ratio

Comment: "One reason is that it is usually difficult to model a variable which has restricted range, such as probability". What is the difficulty faced when numbers are in a restricted range?

Comment: The output of equation is not restricted so thats why